# Azure backup - File system consistent , Application consistent and Crash consistency

Tags: azure, file, crash, backup, consistency

I am trying to understand the difference between File system consistent and crash consistent backups provided by Azure. 
The majority of the information that I find is from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-introduction).
 I see Application consistent backup is to ensure that all memory data and pending I/O are accounted for perhaps by using a quiescing process so proper snapshot can be taken. However bit confused between the other two. I see Crash consistent is one which doesn't consider the in-memory, pending I/Os and only considers backing up what has been written. But then what exactly would be meant by file-consistent backup? I don't find any definition. As a result when the docs mention that by default Linux VM backups are File system consistent if not using pre/post scripts, I am not understanding the implications. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example to demark the difference is : when a recovery point is file-system consistent, there won't be any file system check performed to make sure that file system is not corrupted. In case of crash consistency, after a VM boots up, a file-system check may be performed and based on that there can be potentially a data loss because of corruption of file system. So, it is always better to strive for file system consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it could very well be that a file system consistent backup might contain corrupted files but they are not caught since the no automatic error check and fix is being run, which would run for crash consistent. So won't it be more riskier to have file consistent with potential hidden corruptions? It seems crash consistent is the next stage where file consistent back up has been corrected for file errors by running error checks on VM restarts. Is this understanding correct? So I am not understanding why file consistency is better of the two.

Comment: If there are file system corruption, you don't get file system consistent snapshot. The fact that a recovery point is filesystem consistent means that it is crash consistent and in addition it is also file system consistent. So, it is definitely greater than crash consistent point.